# URL contains page number but this number is unknown

Tags: r, import, zip, quandl

I'm trying in R to get the list of tickers from every exchange covered by `Quandl`.

There are 2 ways:

1) For every exchange the provide the zipped csv with all ticker. The URL looks like this (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - API key, YYY - code of exchange):
https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases/YYY/codes?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
This looks pretty promissing, but I was not able to read the file with `read.table` or e.g `fread`. Don't know why. Is it because of the API key? `read.table` is supposed to read zip files with no problem.

2) I was able to go further with the 2nd way. They provide URL to the csv of tickers. E.g.:

https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets.csv?database_code=YYY&per_page=100&sort_by=id&page=1&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

As you see, URL contains page number. The problem is they only mention it below in text, that you need to run this URL many time (e.g. 56 for LSE) in order to get the full list. I was able to do it like this:

```
pages <- 1:100 # "100" is taken just to be big enough
Source <- c("LSE","FSE", ...) # vector of exchange codes
QUANDL_API_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
TICKERS = lapply(sprintf(
               "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets.csv?
               database_code=%s&per_page=100&sort_by=id&page=%s&api_key=%s",
               Source,pages,QUANDL_API_KEY),
         FUN=fread,
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 TICKERS <- do.call(rbind, TICKERS)
```

The problem is I just put 100 pages, but when R tryies to get the non-existing page (e.g. #57) it delivers an error and do not go further. I was trying to do smth like `iferror`, but failed.

Could you pls give some hints?